# editing apache vhosts and ubuntu hosts file?

Tags: 11.04, apache2, hosts, virtualhost

I have just installed ubuntu (11.04).

I have installed apache/mysql/php etc.

I have a few sites sitting in

```
/var/www/site1  
/var/www/site2  
/var/www/site3
```

I want to be able to access these at

```
http://site1.local  
http://site2.local  
http://site3.local
```

So in my hosts file I have

```
127.0.0.1   site1.local  
127.0.0.1   site2.local  
127.0.0.1   site3.local
```

Then I have copied `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` 3 times.

so now I have:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1  
/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2  
/etc/apache2/sites-available/site3
```

These all look like (with appropriate sitex names)

```
<VirtualHost site1.local>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/site1/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In the terminal I then call

`sudo a2ensite site1 site2 site3 && sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`

Which seems to work,
except only one of the vhosts works at the same time (including default),
What am I doing wrong?

---

When I run the reload command I get

> - Reloading web server config apache2
>     apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,
>     using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
>     [Fri Apr 15 10:45:27 2011] [warn]
>     NameVirtualHost *:80 has no
>     VirtualHosts

Comment: @Hailwood: Are there any error messages or message output when you do `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` ?

Comment: @EvilPhoenix: Check the update :)

Comment: Was curious, because that matches the same error(s) I get, which explains my interest in this question you asked.

Comment: Weird, I am surprised there is not an apache.stackexchange.com

Comment: btw, just found serverfault so I have asked http://serverfault.com/questions/259890/editing-apache-vhosts-and-ubuntu-hosts-file as well.

Comment: ah very good.  I'll watch here AND there :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File: **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 site1.local
127.0.0.1 site2.local
127.0.0.1 site3.local
```

File: **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
[...]
NameVirtualHost *:80
[...]
```

Files: **/etc/apache2/sites-available/site{i}.local.conf** (instead of {i} insert number: 1 or 2 or 3)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site{i}.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site{i}
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

In directory **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/** create symbolic links:

```
@site{i}.local.conf
```

Restart apache and have fun :)

Comment: One note is that the line suggested for `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` was found in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` which is imported by `apache2.conf`

Answer (score 0):

There is a script that makes this simple for you - https://github.com/RoverWire/virtualhost

This eventually does the same thins as explained by the answers given but does it in just one command eg. -

```
sudo virtualhost create mysite.local my_site
```

It also allows you to delete a host you created

```
sudo virtualhost delete mysite.local my_site
```

Just note that the "my_dir" assumes that it starts after /var/www

So if your site folder is in /var/www/my_site

You should run this (pass directory path without /var/www) -

```
sudo virtualhost create mysite.local my_site
```

You can also modify the script file & remove the default path "/var/www" so that you can pass an absolute path to the site directory